# How can I compile sfml project via command line on mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, sfml

I am trying to compile a sfml project via command line under mac osx. Currently, I'm not able to get it to compile. Any help guys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the simple window application they include as part of the templates. I was able to compile it with the following command.

`g++ -framework OpenGL -framework SFML -framework SFML-window main.cpp`

I hope that helps

Comment: This did not work for me. I had to run "g++ -F /Library/Frameworks -c main.cpp" and then "g++ main.o -o main -framework sfml-window -framework sfml-graphics -framework sfml-system" for it to work correctly. Otherwise I got an error with wrong architecture.

Answer (score 6):

You can compile with only one instruction:

```
g++ -framework sfml-window -framework sfml-graphics -framework sfml-system main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. :-)